# Checking static_cast vs reinterpret_cast in an assert

Tags: c++, casting, static

I saw some code along the lines of

```
ASSERT(static_cast<MyClass*>(p) == reinterpret_cast<MyClass*>(p))
```

I think p was a base type pointer.
What is the purpose of this assert? Is it checking that MyClass is not part of some multiple inheritance hierarchy (or anything that would cause a known cast to change the address value of p)?

Answer (score 2):

Since the behavior of `reinterpret_cast<T*>(p)` is implementation specific for most uses, nearly all uses of `reinterpret_cast<T*>(p)` are a sign that the code is highly non-portable and, ideally, avoided. Sometimes `reinterpret_cast`s can't be avoided but trying to assert on its property is almost certainly a sign that the code is trying to do something it shouldn't try.

From a practical point of view, there are a number of `static_cast<T*>(p)` which are allowed and which may change the address of a pointer. In particular, `static_cast<T*>(p)` is allowed if `p` as obtained by an implicit conversion from a `T*` to the value `p` which is [obviously] some other pointer type (including `void*`). When the implicit conversion adjusted the pointer, the `static_cast<T*>(p)` will undo the adjustment. However, the standard doesn't specify under which conditions the pointer address may change.

It seems the assert wants to guard against cases where the implementation needs to change the address of the pointer. Since there are no standard guarantees on when the address of a pointer converted to a base class changes nor what `reinterpret_cast<T*>(p)` does, it is impossible to tell what the author of this assertion had in mind. Whatever it is, there is no guarantee that the guard will guard against whatever was intended.

In my mind the `ASSERT()` quoted above states: "do not use this code!"

Comment: How should an implementation know whether a concrete pointer value (in this case `p`) was implictely converted? Or is the condition that pointers of type `decltype(p)` CAN generally be converted from `T*` (so its not a matter the concrete pointer but the pointer type itself) ?

Comment: @Paranaix: the implementation won't know if the pointer was implicitly converted from the type you cast it to. The implementer has to guarantee that this is the case, e.g., because the user _knows_. A typical use of this rule is to pass a `void*` converted from a `T*` to something registering a callback and restoring the `T*` in the called function.

Comment: I think you missunderstood me. I talked about the actuall c++ implementation / runtime and refered to `In particular, static_cast<T*>(p) is allowed if p as obtained by an implicit conversion from a T* to the value p`. How should a implementation of `static_cast` know this?

Comment: @Paranaix: I think I understood your question perfectly! If you try to use `static_cast<T*>(p)` when it is not allowed, you have [undefined behavior](http://dspace.dial.pipex.com/town/green/gfd34/art/bloopers.html). There is no need for the implementation to know whether the cast is allowed because when it is being used there is an implicit promise that it is a correct use.